# Adding metro ui css to asp.net single page application

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, single-page-application

I have been trying to add the Metro UI CSS to a new SPA application using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web. I am able to add it successfully to MVC application using the same, but for some reason I cannot add a class to the  attribute using _Layout.cshtml as well as I am unable to find the css and js in the page source after rendering, even though they have been properly referenced. Is there a particular way (different from tradition MVC) to add nuget packages such as Metro UI in SPA applications?
here is the link to the instructions I used: http://pepitosolis.wordpress.com/2013/12/29/using-metro-ui-css-version-2-0-with-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was to change the following line From

BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/**metro-ui**").Include("~/Scripts/metro-ui/jquery.ui.widget.js").Include("~/Scripts/metro-ui/metro-*"));

to

BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/**metro**").Include("~/Scripts/metro-ui/jquery.ui.widget.js").Include("~/Scripts/metro-ui/metro-*"));

Comment: Rather than just post the change, can you explain what it does?

Comment: Please format your answer (and maybe highlight the part that changed).  For formatting help, click on the little `help` link next to the text box where you type your answer.